# Check for network status update while application killed

Tags: android, android-10.0

My scenario is the following:

I'm working on a chat application and I would like to implement some type synchronization service that starts itself when device recovers network connection. Anytime device has network connection again, unsent messages are going to be automatically sent. With independence of application state (foregorund, background or killed).

Options tried:

**1. Broadcast Receiver with android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE**
This scenario only works when the application is active (Foreground or Backround) but stops working when app is killed.

**2. Foreground service**
A notification is going to be shown all the time which is not ideal. Also I want to avoid draining users' battery.

**3. AndroidX.Work.Worker**

```
 PeriodicWorkRequest networkCheckingPeriodicWork = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder.
                From<ConnectivityChangeWroker>(repeatInterval:30, repeatIntervalTimeUnit: Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeUnit.Minutes, flexInterval:25, flexIntervalTimeUnit:Java.Util.Concurrent.TimeUnit.Minutes)
                .SetConstraints(new Constraints.Builder().SetRequiredNetworkType(AndroidX.Work.NetworkType.Connected)
                .SetRequiredNetworkType(AndroidX.Work.NetworkType.Unmetered).Build()).Build();

            WorkManager.Instance.EnqueueUniquePeriodicWork("", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.Replace, networkCheckingPeriodicWork);


public class ConnectivityChangeWroker : AndroidX.Work.Worker
{
    public ConnectivityChangeWroker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParameters) : base(context, workerParameters)
    {

    }

    public override Result DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            //Start synch service

            return Result.InvokeSuccess();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Result.InvokeFailure();
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case, I'm not achieving the desired behaviour. For my undestanding, I just set a periodic work that checks for network connection, and if there is one, runs **DoWork()** method.

**-- EDIT --**
**4.JobService**

```
Java.Lang.Class javaClass = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ConnectivityChangeJob));
            ComponentName component = new ComponentName(Application.Context, javaClass);

            JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, component)
                                     .SetRequiredNetworkType(Android.App.Job.NetworkType.Any)
                                     .SetOverrideDeadline(5000)
                                     .SetPersisted(true)
                                     .Build();

            JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)GetSystemService(JobSchedulerService);
            jobScheduler.Schedule(jobInfo);




[Service(Name = "Extintores.ConnectivityChangeJob", Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
public class ConnectivityChangeJob : JobService
{
    private Intent startServiceIntent;

    public ConnectivityChangeJob()
    {

    }

    public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters jobParams)
    {
       //Start synchService

        return true;
    }

    public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters jobParams)
    {
        return true; //Reschedule the job
    }
}
```

But in this case, **OnStartJob** is only fired the first time the applicatio is opened and, apparently, never again.

Is there any way I can achieve what I'm aming for?

**-- EDIT --**
I want to achieve the same bahaviour as applications as WhatsApp. When it detects network connection again, automatically all unsent messages are going to be send.

Comment: The WhatsApp works as the system application. So it can run in background all the time. But your app is a third party application and will be killed by the operation system when it work in the background for a little time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the AndroidX.Work.Worker is the best option.

In `DoWork` you should update databases and send requests.

Besides worker supports [long-running workers](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running)

Example DownloadWorker:

```
class DownloadWorker(context: Context, parameters: WorkerParameters) :
   CoroutineWorker(context, parameters) {

   private val notificationManager =
       context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as
               NotificationManager

   override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
       val inputUrl = inputData.getString(KEY_INPUT_URL)
                      ?: return Result.failure()
       val outputFile = inputData.getString(KEY_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME)
                      ?: return Result.failure()
       // Mark the Worker as important
       val progress = "Starting Download"
       setForeground(createForegroundInfo(progress))
       download(inputUrl, outputFile)
       return Result.success()
   }

   private fun download(inputUrl: String, outputFile: String) {
       // Downloads a file and updates bytes read
       // Calls setForeground() periodically when it needs to update
       // the ongoing Notification
   }
   // Creates an instance of ForegroundInfo which can be used to update the
   // ongoing notification.
   private fun createForegroundInfo(progress: String): ForegroundInfo {
       val id = applicationContext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id)
       val title = applicationContext.getString(R.string.notification_title)
       val cancel = applicationContext.getString(R.string.cancel_download)
       // This PendingIntent can be used to cancel the worker
       val intent = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
               .createCancelPendingIntent(getId())

       // Create a Notification channel if necessary
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           createChannel()
       }

       val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, id)
           .setContentTitle(title)
           .setTicker(title)
           .setContentText(progress)
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_work_notification)
           .setOngoing(true)
           // Add the cancel action to the notification which can
           // be used to cancel the worker
           .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_delete, cancel, intent)
           .build()

       return ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notification)
   }

   @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
   private fun createChannel() {
       // Create a Notification channel
   }

   companion object {
       const val KEY_INPUT_URL = "KEY_INPUT_URL"
       const val KEY_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "KEY_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME"
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem with Worker is the way executions are handled. A periodic task is scheduled and executed based on system constraints. It could be a solution but I'm aming for something like WhatsApp behaviour (see question edit)